# Ignore errors in mysql by reading from some MySQL dump

Tags: sql, insert, duplicates, mysql

I got an MySQL dump with ONLY insert statements. I tried to import it like this:

```
mysql> \. racktablesTabellen.sql
```

which always worked for me, till now because I got some errors I have to ignore. Can anybody tell me how to Ignore errors and just keep on with the entries when I got an sql dump with only insert statements ?

Comment: Primary Key duplicate errors. Basically I just want to ignore them and keep on with the other entries.

Comment: But how can I put that IGNORE in there ?? It's just got a dump with thousands of lines with INSERT statements Oo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to remove the PRIMARY KEY from your table, import and add the PRIAMRY KEY again with ALTER IGNORE syntax.

Comment: Your answer might work as well but I am too dumb to check the syntax xP I just did this in my vi :%s/INSERT/INSERT IGNORE worked I guess

Comment: I did this  based off previous comment: zcat db.sql.gz | sed -e 's/INSERT/INSERT IGNORE/' | mysql -u user -p dbname